# How to index cached dynamic php pages & how to keep only latest pages

Tags: php, caching

We have an online php search utility that we would like to improve the performance by caching result pages so we can display them when users do the same search after the first one instead for retrieving the same data from the database.

I did same reading and I understand the simple idea of checking if the static cached page exists at the beginning of the php script and if not to create it at the bottom.

## My questions

1) what would be the best way to do the search for the cached static pages in case we have many (thousands)?

2) What would be the best way to keep only static pages from the last 24 hours and delete the old irrelevant ones.

Hope you can share relevant experience or interesting ideas to help us create a good caching system for our site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible options, depending on what your hardware is best for :

- static caching : Each time there is a search, create a static html page (no php in it) and save it on disk. Create a physical path that apache can understand, so that when the HTML is not there, a PHP file is called, and when it is, the static file is called. That is using `mod_rewrite`. Use a cron job to clear old pages using the time of creation of the file.
- use the database : Create a table that has a key column, which is the search string, a timestamp of creation, and a result page, which is the complete rendered output.

In both cases, if the cache is there, use it. Use a cron process to delete stale cache entries.

Comment: Any idea what is faster - searching for a row from a db table of 10,000 rows by index key (100 character) or searching for the same key as a file name in a folder with 10,000 files?

Comment: it really depends on your server. if it is virtuallized, or your disks are slowish (SATA), i/o is the bottleneck and hence the database will always be faster (assuming indexed varchar as key). 

if however you're using a enterprise solution (eg iSCSI mounted storage on high performance SAN), Apache can outperform it. If you go this route, you should definently use a folder scheme to avoid having tens of thousant of files in one directory -- better use part of the key in the folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a hash (like md5) that is based on the input: query, page, filter settings etc.
2. Keep an expiration date on the caches.

---

If you have complex input, say:

```
$input = array(
    "query" => "foo",
    "filter" => array(
        "category" => "movies"
    ),
    "page" => 1
);
```

You can easily reduce this to a hash by `md5(serialize($input));`

Comment: I think that md5 is very expensive - doing these conversions for every call might not be the best solution if our goal is to minimize server tasks - am I right?

Comment: `md5` is pretty fast these days. You can substitute for your preferred hasing algo.